# Make docker env variables from an `.env` file available in build step (Dockerfile) & during run-time in container

Tags: docker, docker-compose, dockerfile, environment-variables

##### Premises

Given a file `oneSourceOfTruth.env`:

```bash
FOO=42
... (many entries)
```

and a `docker-compose.yml`:

```yaml
services:
  my-service:
    dockefile: ./Dockerfile
    env_file: oneSourceOfTruth.env
```

##### Objective

I'd like to have all variables from `oneSourceOfTruth.env` available in the `Dockerfile` **during the build step** via `docker compose build` **as well as in the container during runtime** (`docker compose up`). The variables are *static* in the sense that they are once set (before the build) and then never change again for a specific build and the containers that spawn from the build.

Unfortunately, it does not work with `env_file` option as it only passes the env variables to the *containers*. The env variables are not available during the build (e.g. with a `RUN` command inside the Dockerfile).

*Sidenote*: I don't necessarily need to access the env variables directly inside the `docker-compose.yml` file itself, e.g. we *don't* have something like the following in our `docker-compose.yml` file.

```yaml
args:
   - FOO=$FOO
```

##### ⭕ Constraint

The `oneSourceOfTruth.env` file is quite long. For scalability reasons and better code quality, I'd like to regard this file as the "one source of truth" where env variables are *declared* and *set*. That is, introducing (removing) an env variable should only imply I have to add (remove) one line in this file alone.

##### ❎ Ways to solve the objective without respecting the constraint.

- From [this comment on an issue](https://github.com/docker/compose/issues/5600#issuecomment-359900819). Use

```
ARG FOO
ENV FOO $FOO
```

in your Dockerfile. Do this for every single variable. One user knows what I feel about this approach (see [here](https://github.com/docker/compose/issues/5600#issuecomment-718228920)):

> This is not a practical solution whatsoever if you have a big environment file. This makes development tedious and unnecessarily annoying where if you can just read environment variables passed from the compose file. Hard-coding variables is never good, because if you would then want to add more environment variables you have to edit multiple files.

The solution proposed [here](https://github.com/docker/compose/issues/5600#issuecomment-727905877) `source oneSourceOfTruth.env && docker-compose build` did not work for me (env variables were not populated / were empty).

- Pass the env varialbes in the `environment` section in the `docker-compose.yml` file as described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/72644182/9655481) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/68831814/9655481).

##### Other answers I've checked out:

- [Difference between `.env` file and `env_file` option](https://stackoverflow.com/a/74544228/9655481)
- Related, but didn't help: [How to get an environment variable value into Dockerfile during "docker build"?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19537645/how-to-get-an-environment-variable-value-into-dockerfile-during-docker-build)

##### Avoid XY problem

Maybe this is an [XY problem](https://xyproblem.info/). For the sake of completeness, here is why I'd like to get this problem solved ;)

Inside our `Dockerfile`, we use the following Rails command to precompile our assets:

```
RUN DB_ADAPTER=nulldb bundle exec rails assets:precompile
```

Unfortunately, this will spawn the entire Rails machinery (at least we can avoid connecting to the DB with the `DB_ADAPTER=nulldb` adapter from [here](https://github.com/nulldb/nulldb)). There existed an option `initialize_on_precompile` that one could set to `false` to avoid booting up Rails for this task, see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/41539826/9655481)). However, this option was removed from the Rails codebase, see [this commit](https://github.com/rails/rails/commit/2d5a6de).

This means we are forced to load env variables also in the `precompile` task. As stated, with the key `env_file` in our `docker-compose.yml` file, the env variables are only available in the containers and not during the build (where we need them for the `precompile` task). A workaround so far was to use `ENV("Foo", nil)` everywhere in our ruby on rails code such that the variable default to `nil` if not specified. This way everything works: during the `precompile` task, all env variables are `nil` but we don't need them anyways for the mere task of precompiling our assets. During the production run-time, the env variable will then be available.

But with this approach, we silently ignore the case when we really forget to set an env variable. Then, also during production, the variable will be `nil` and we only recognize this by the effects it causes. Therefore, our solution so far is really just a workaround and should be fixed. If a variable is not available, it should raise a `KeyError` during the build step of the project and not just when a user complains that something in our app is not working. This can be achieved by using `ENV("Foo")` instead of `ENV("Foo", nil)`, but now we get the key error during the `precompile` task since the env variables are not available in the `Dockerfile` (where we execute the `precompile` task). That's exactly the problem ;)

Comment: ``direnv`` is an application that sets environmental variables up when you navigate to the directory (by loading up a .envrc file). If your build directory is its own, you could add a .envrc file with all your ``oneSourceOfTruth.env`` contents into it in the form of ``export FOO=42 ...`` and when you go into your directory to build, all the variables should be accessible in the system environment (not just in docker). You can even split off private variables into its own .envrc-like file and call it from ``.envrc`` flie to separate sensitive settings. Maybe this is helpful? https://direnv.net/

Comment: If people are interested to see how we implemented the solution in a real-world project, see [this diff](https://github.com/MaMpf-HD/mampf/pull/597/files#diff-f9a478fcb734509a41e1332346844310915a683e6ad7d65039486af31ef8acd0R115-R116).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In addition to not matching well with Docker's `ENV` primitive, the other practical problem with this setup is that the environment gets reset at the end of each `RUN` command.

If you only need the contents of the file once, then you can use the standard shell `.` command to read it in within the context of a single `RUN` command.  (Some shells have a similar `source` command, but it is not part of the shell standard, and I'd avoid it in most cases.)

```bash
WORKDIR /app
COPY ./ ./ # includes .env file
RUN . oneSourceOfTruth.env && \
    DB_ADAPTER=nulldb bundle exec rails assets:precompile
# RUN echo $Foo  # environment variables won't be set any more
# CMD echo $Foo  # nor in the eventual container
```

You can work around the `CMD` problem by writing a shell script that reads in the environment file and then runs the command it's passed.  That script can be the image's `ENTRYPOINT`.

```bash
#!/bin/sh
. /app/oneSourceOfTruth.env
exec "$@"
```

```bash
ENTRYPOINT ["/app/with-environment"]
CMD echo $Foo  # will be set now
```

If you need the environment to be set on every `RUN` command, then you can override the Dockerfile `SHELL` to run this script too.  This defines the interpreter that's used for shell-syntax `RUN` and `CMD` commands (not JSON-array syntax), and you could inject a wrapper script here too.

```bash
SHELL ["/app/with-environment", "/bin/sh", "-c"]
RUN echo $Foo
CMD echo $Foo
# CMD ["/bin/sh", "-c", "echo $Foo"] # will not have the environment
```

The one caution with this last setup is that a `docker run` or Compose `command:` override won't see the Dockerfile `SHELL` and the environment variables won't be set there.  You need the `ENTRYPOINT` wrapper for that.

Comment: Thanks a lot, that helped. Unfortunately, another issue is that while we have the `oneSourceOfTruth.env` available on the host machine, it's not available in the build context (a github repo). Mounting a volume or a bind mount didn't work (file not found). However, in the github repo we have a dummy `docker.env` file, so we ended up sourcing that (the `assets:precompile` task is not even relying on the correct env values). Using a new buildkit of docker seems to allow multiple build contexts, but we get moby-ssh errors with it, so we stick with the old buildkit and the dummy env file.

Answer (score 2):

You have the `oneSourceOfTruth.env` available on the machine, where the Docker build happens, right?

Then you can do something like this:

```
# ...
WORKDIR /app
COPY oneSourceOfTruth.env /app/oneSourceOfTruth.env
RUN source /app/oneSourceOfTruth.env
RUN DB_ADAPTER=nulldb bundle exec rails assets:precompile
RUN rm -f /app/oneSourceOfTruth.env
# ...
```

Please bear in mind, that the final Docker image should *not* contain any secrets. Therefore I'd recommend deleting the `oneSourceOfTruth.env` from the image again file before finishing the build or do a multi-stage build where you do the build in the first step and copy the build result (without the `oneSourceOfTruth.env`) to the second build step.

At runtime, pass the `env_file` in your Docker Compose config like you already did.

Comment: Thanks for your answer which got the main point across. I still accepted David's answer as it went into more detail and also clarified that you have to source the env file in the same `RUN` command where you want to have the env variables available. It also listed some more caveats to watch out for. Thanks for noting the security aspect here, that's certainly an important point to watch out for.